# Lazy Loading with custom height and width in android

Tags: android, lazy-loading

I am Using Android Famous Lazy Loading example. the link is https://github.com/thest1/LazyList
i don't know how to set the height and width of my requirements.(e.g height=150dp and width=100dp). can anyone please help me out. i know the answer is lying within ImageLoader class(Especially in decodeFile() method).

Comment: If you want to display an image, You would have to call `ImageLoader.displayImage("Your URL", ImageView);` Set your width and height for this imageview. What is the big deal with that?

Comment: How about setting Height and width attributes in ImageView?

Comment: I already set the height and width of imageview but, the image i get from url comes in square in size.

Comment: All the images in the world is square or rectangle. If you want to resize it, Define the layout height  = "xx.dip" as you intended. and set the scaleType to center.

Comment: @HiteshKamani I am run this example, and change image size. It's working for me,there is no problem.Only change imageview height and width in item.xml file.

Comment: ok. thanks a lot to all of you.